# How can I write specific words on terminal( mainly GIT)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When We press the uparrow button. it types "code.". can we write other words when we press some key? I want to write ./a.exe on the terminal when pressing some key. How can we do so in Visual studio code?

Comment: the arrow keys shows the command from history. If you have ran ./a.exe, you can press up arrow to browse it from history. If it is the last command you have executed it will be shown first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integrated terminal inside the VS Code is very much customizable when it comes to key bindings. The [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_send-text-from-a-keybinding) says:

> The `workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence` command can be used to send
>   a specific sequence of text to the terminal, including escape
>   sequences. This enables things like sending arrow keys, enter, cursor
>   moves, etc. The example below shows the sorts of things you can
>   achieve with this feature, it jumps over the word to the left of the
>   cursor (Ctrl+Left arrow) and presses backspace:
>
> ```
> {
>    "key": "ctrl+u",
>    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",  
>    "args": { "text": "\u001b[1;5D\u007f" }
> }
> ```
>
> This feature supports variable substitution.
>
> Note that the command only works with the \u0000 format for using
>   characters via their character code (not \x00).